# Portmanteau Test for VAR

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, autocorrelation, vector-autoregression, lags

I am new into working with VAR models and have a fundamental question regarding model diagnostics. 
As suggested in Kilian and Lütkepohl (2017, pp. 52-53), I would like to run a Portmanteau test for residual autocorrelation. How to determine the order h that I should test up to? Kilian and Lütkepohl (p. 53) say

> "The number h of autocovariance terms in the test statistic should be
>   considerably larger than p for a good approximation to the null
>   distribution. Choosing h too large, however, may undermine the power
>   of the test. In practice, usually a number of different values of h is
>   considered."

I have found various rule of thumbs (e.g. https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/ljung-box-test/) but I am not sure if these are appropriate for VARs.

In my concrete example, I have fitted a six-variable VAR with 18 lags and monthly data. Should I use e.g. h=24 or run a loop for different values?

I would very much appreciate any literature recommendations or hints in general!

Thanks in advance!